# std::vector initialization of class member

Tags: c++

I have read that `std::vector` always initializes it's objects with their `default values` say for an `int` it is `0`. The same should be applicable even for `classes` where the `default constructor` is called. However the results shown by a test program are a bit different :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class A 
{
    public:
      int i;
      A(){};
};

class B
{
    public:
        int i;
        B() = default;
};

template <typename T>
void seev (const vector<T> &v)
{
    for (auto &x:v)
    {
        cout << x.i << ' ';
    }
    cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> vi(5);  // just to show that std::vector always default initializes values & hence int will be 0 here
    vector<A> va(5);
    vector<B> vb(5);

    for (auto x: vi)
    cout << x << ' ';
    cout << '\n';

    seev (va);
    seev (vb);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is :-

```
0 0 0 0 0
8854016 0 8847696 0 8854016
0 0 0 0 0
```

My question is why was the value of member `i` undefined for `A` & not for `B` ?  What difference did the `constructor` signatures :-

```
A() {}
```

&

```
B() = default;
```

make ?

Comment: `default` constructor doesn't mean _empty_ constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When creating a vector with a specific size, the vector doesn't set default values, it uses something called [*value initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) which is something completely different.

For primitive types, like e.g. `int`, that means the value will be zero-initialized (i.e. zero). But for objects with constructors the default constructor (if it has one) will be used.

In the case of your `A` class, the default constructor does not initialize the `i` member variable, so it will be uninitialized and have an *indeterminate* value, by printing that value you have *undefined behavior*.

As for the `B` class it's a [*POD type*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType) which means that value initialization of the whole object will also value-initialize all members. `B` is a POD type because it has a [trivial default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Trivial_default_constructor) (which `A` does not have).

Answer (score 6):

There is a difference between *default initialization* and *value initialization*. The difference is shown for `B` but not for `A`:

- When a class has a non-`= default`ed constructor, this constructor is called when either default or value initialization is used. Its responsibility is to initialize all members appropriately.
- When a class either has no constructor or an `= default`ed default constructor the initialization of the members depends on how the object is constructed: when initializing the object without parenthesis default initialization is done which leaves subobjects without a default constructor uninitialized. When initializing the object with parenthesis value initialization is done which value initializes all subobjects. Value initialization of built-in types mean they get a suitable zero value while default initialization of built-in types means they are left uninitialized.

Since `A` has an explicitly written default constructor, its constructor needs to initialize all members which aren't of class type with a default constructor. `B` has an implicitly written default constructor and default or value initialization is performed as necessary for the subobjects.

The objects in a `std::vector<T>` are constructed using `T()` (if no other arguments are provides as is the case, e.g., for `push_back()` or `emplace_back()`). For `A` members that means they are left uninitialized, for `B` members that means they are zero initialized.

Answer (score 5):

```
A() {};
```

You are not initializing `A::i` in `A()` so its value is unspecified after value initialization. This behaviour is different to what you would get with a compiler-provided default constructor.

```
A() = default;
```

Defining as `default` on the other hand has the effect of providing a constructor with the same semantics of the compiler-synthesized default constructor. That is to say, `A::i` would get value-initialized (and therefore zero-initialized) when an `A` object is value initialized with expressions such as `A()` or `A{}`.

---

Note: this can be fixed by either dropping the definition of the default constructor, define it as `default`, or explicitly initialize `i`.

```
struct A 
{
  // Compiler provided A() will initialize i
  // when A is value initialized
      int i;
};
```

or, equivalently in terms of initialization semantics,

```
struct A 
{
      int i;
      A() = default; // useful if other constructors defined
};
```

Comment: I know how to mend the problem @juanchopanza. I just want to know the what is the difference between `A(){}` & `B()=default` & why doesn't empty brace default initialize `i`.

Comment: @CppNITR OK, I re-phrased and changed the emphasis. TL;DR you get back the behaviour of the compiler provided default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

An "empty" constructor will not initialize anything, so the fact that `va` contains zero is just luck/coincidence. The `default` constructor will do nothing either, so they will produce the same thing. What you are seeing is undefined behaviour (or unspecified behaviour perhaps - as we shouldn't really expect world war three to break out because of an uninitialized variable).

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that `std::vector` is supposed to call the `default constructor` & not set the values by default. The default constructor of `int` sets it's value to `0` hence you get a `std::vector<int>` with all values initialized with 0. However you default constructor of `A` is empty & hence it doesn't initialize `i` with any value. If you define the constructor as :-

```
A() { i = 0; }
```

Then your vector would definitely initialize the `i` of the objects of `A` with `0`. What default does is this :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        A()
        {
            cout << "Default constructed A\n";
        }
        A (A &obj)
        {
            cout << "Copy constructed A\n";
        }
};

class X
{
    int x;
    double d;
    bool b;
    A obj;
    public:
        X() = default;
        void show()
        {
            cout << fixed << x << ' ' << d << ' ' << b << '\n';
        }
};

int main()
{
    cout << boolalpha;
    vector<X> v(1);
    v[0].show();
    return 0;
}

/* Output :-
Default constructed A
0 0.000000 false
*/
```

What `B() = default;` roughly means as far I get from this test code that it is a replacement for :-

```
B()
{
   i = 0;
   d = 0.00;
   b = false;
   // obj is default initialized
}
```

ie the initialization of the `data members` with their `default values` (for primitives) or `default constructors` (for classes). But this is only for `runtime initialization` which means for locally created objects the definition is same as `B() = {}`.

So the thing was that class `A` had a user defined `constructor` (with an empty body) & hence didn't initialize because that's how the programmer defined it. On the other hand class `B` had a constructor that was left on to the compiler to call implicitly. Hence for local objects it didn't do any specific initialization but for dynamic objects (like that of a `std::vector`) it did the `value type initialization`.

Comment: `int` doesn't have a default constructor, and `B() = default;` does not do what you say it does.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley i will look into it again, thnx for recommending

Comment: @BenjaminLindley i think my interpretation is right, look at the initialization of `A obj` in class `X`. `default` does call the default constructor & yes in case of primitives it does default initialization

Comment: No, your interpretation is not correct. Hopefully this makes it clear that it is not: http://ideone.com/6JI3qj